# Can we catch apex cpu time limit exception in catch block salesforce?

Tags: salesforce

Using apex:Message we can display only custom message for apex cpu time limit exception.

Answer (score 3):

You cannot catch the apex CPU time limit exception but in your code you can always check the limits, refer to the documentation [here](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_methods_system_limits.htm). In your case, you can check `Limits.getCpuTime()` which you could call after every few iterations or whenever it seems appropriate and if you find the time close to the limit you can simply stop the execution and pass your own custom error message in `ApexPages.addMessage(new ApexPages.Message(ApexPages.Severity.ERROR,'Error: Your Custom Error Message'))`

Answer (score 1):

Nope, sorry. You can't catch them the same way you can't catch exception caused by `System.assert()`.

https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_gov_limits.htm

> Because Apex runs in a multitenant environment, the Apex runtime
>   engine strictly enforces limits to ensure that runaway Apex code or
>   processes don’t monopolize shared resources. If some Apex code exceeds
>   a limit, the associated governor issues **a runtime exception that
>   cannot be handled**.

Comment: Thanks!!....Actually I want to display error message on Apex cpu time limit exception to user. So is there any other way i can do this?

Comment: Not in the context where it happens, SF will display their own ugly black text on white background fatal error. But if you have another context (maybe it wasn't a VF page but a batch job. Or inbound email handler) - you could try querying the AsyncApexJob table. Batch & @future fails end up there, even if there was no debug logging enabled. InboundEmailHandler exceptions can be forwarded to dedicated mailbox.